# How to add data to datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to add data to datatable within a loop in c# but I cannot.
I use this code but it runs 1 time not more.  When `i=2` it dose not work.
Please help.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ProductId");
dt.Columns.Add("ProductTotalPrice");
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dr["ProductId"] = i.ToString();
    dr["ProductTotalPrice"] = (i*1000).ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

That's cause you are creating only one `DataRow` outside loop and so you are actually over writing the old values in that row with new one's. Your row creation should be inside loop and thus you will have new row per iteration like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ProductId");
dt.Columns.Add("ProductTotalPrice");
DataRow dr = null;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow(); // have new row on each iteration
    dr["ProductId"] = i.ToString();
    dr["ProductTotalPrice"] = (i*1000).ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ProductId"] = i.ToString();
    dr["ProductTotalPrice"] = (i*1000).ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Should work.

Each time you need to add different dataRow. You're trying to add the same.

Comment: Why it should work? you might also want to include that explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another simple way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(i, i * 1000);
}
```